# How do I traverse an array and sum every n elements in java?

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I'm trying to traverse an int array of length 100 and sum the value of every n elements and store the sum in a different array.

This is what I have so far:

```
currentNum = 100;
int[] sumArray = new int[100/n+1]
while(currentNum) {
    for (int j = currentNum; j < currentNum + n;j++) {
        sum += intArr[j];
    }
    currentNum = currentNum - n; 
}
```

Comment: This couldn't possibly compile.

Comment: Please post a working, minimal example, and explain what the problem is with it.

Comment: Line 1: currentNum has not been declared. Line 2: n has not been declared, and there is no semicolon. Line 3: not sure if Java can convert `int` to `boolean`. Make sure those things are fixed, then post what problems you are actually having.

Comment: I'm sure if Java can convert int to boolean, not

Answer (score 1):

```
int[] sum(int[] array, int n) {
    int sums[] = new int[(array.length + n - 1) / n];// thanks to @popovitsj

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (i % n == 0)
            sums[i / n] = 0;// initialize
        sums[i / n] += array[i];// summarize
    }

    return sums;
}
```

first `sums` elements will hold sum of n elements, last - `array.length % n` elements

Comment: `array.length / n + 1` is incorrect. For example, it will fail for length=10 and n=5. Correct is `(array.length + n - 1) / n`

Comment: yes, thanks for your note. I've changed to another working version: `array.length / n + (array.length % n > 0 ? 1 : 0)`

Comment: That's an incredibly circumround way to divide a by b and round up, particularly since popovitsj already mentioned the standard way to do it, which is shorter and more efficient.

Comment: Ok, it's really more efficient